# How do you throw an HTTP error with mod_python

Tags: python, apache, mod-python, http-error

I have a setup where I'm serving simple python pages using the mod_python publisher. At some points I'd like to have the python function raise a standard apache error - for example throwing a 500 error if a required file is missing.  How can I throw an apache error from within a mod_python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a python expert but from [this documentation](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pythonapi.html#module-apache), it would appear that you can do:

```
raise apache.SERVER_RETURN, apache.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Here is a quote of the documentation in case of link rot:

> A handler function will always be passed a reference to a request
>   object. (Throughout this manual, the request object is often referred
>   to by the req variable.)
>
> Every handler can return:
>
> apache.OK, meaning this phase of the request was handled by this
>   handler and no errors occurred.
>
> apache.DECLINED, meaning this handler has not handled this phase of
>   the request to completion and Apache needs to look for another handler
>   in subsequent modules.
>
> apache.HTTP_ERROR, meaning an HTTP error occurred. HTTP_ERROR can be
>   any of the following:
>
> ```
> HTTP_CONTINUE                     = 100
> HTTP_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS          = 101
> HTTP_PROCESSING                   = 102
> HTTP_OK                           = 200
> HTTP_CREATED                      = 201
> HTTP_ACCEPTED                     = 202
> HTTP_NON_AUTHORITATIVE            = 203
> HTTP_NO_CONTENT                   = 204
> HTTP_RESET_CONTENT                = 205
> HTTP_PARTIAL_CONTENT              = 206
> HTTP_MULTI_STATUS                 = 207
> HTTP_MULTIPLE_CHOICES             = 300
> HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY            = 301
> HTTP_MOVED_TEMPORARILY            = 302
> HTTP_SEE_OTHER                    = 303
> HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED                 = 304
> HTTP_USE_PROXY                    = 305
> HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT           = 307
> HTTP_BAD_REQUEST                  = 400
> HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED                 = 401
> HTTP_PAYMENT_REQUIRED             = 402
> HTTP_FORBIDDEN                    = 403
> HTTP_NOT_FOUND                    = 404
> HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED           = 405
> HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE               = 406
> HTTP_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED= 407
> HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT             = 408
> HTTP_CONFLICT                     = 409
> HTTP_GONE                         = 410
> HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED              = 411
> HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED          = 412
> HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE     = 413
> HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE        = 414
> HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE       = 415
> HTTP_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE        = 416
> HTTP_EXPECTATION_FAILED           = 417
> HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY         = 422
> HTTP_LOCKED                       = 423
> HTTP_FAILED_DEPENDENCY            = 424
> HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR        = 500
> HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED              = 501
> HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY                  = 502
> HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE          = 503
> HTTP_GATEWAY_TIME_OUT             = 504
> HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED        = 505
> HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES          = 506
> HTTP_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE         = 507
> HTTP_NOT_EXTENDED                 = 510
> ```
>
> As an alternative to returning an HTTP error code, handlers can signal
>   an error by raising the apache.SERVER_RETURN exception, and providing
>   an HTTP error code as the exception value, e.g.:
>
> ```
> raise apache.SERVER_RETURN, apache.HTTP_FORBIDDEN
> ```

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @usermel2014 That will happen on a 6 year old answer :-) New docs appear to be: http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pythonapi.html#module-apache

Comment: Thanks. The answer is now so much better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's:

```
def my_action(req):
  # all the status code constants are defined in the apache module 
  req.status = apache.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR 
  req.content_type = some_mime_type
  req.write(content)
  raise apache.HTTP_SERVER_RETURN, apache.DONE
```

raising apache.DONE tells Apache not to write out its own error page.